# UL List items with styled decimal numbers

Tags: html, css

I need to create a set of list items where I need to style the list item numbers (decimals) with a border-radius and a background color.

Here is the snapshot of how I want my list items to look like.

[image: The Image is what I am looking for.]

I have tried to put a border radius, background on the li, but I was not able to get the output that I am lookin for.

Here is a **[WORKING LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/ugenb/)** of what I have tried so far. I removed the border-radius, background, etc. as it was not displaying properly.

**The HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li>Text Character</li>
    <li>Text Character</li>
    <li>Text Character</li>
    <li>Text Character</li>
    <li>Text Character</li>
</ul>
```

**The CSS:**

```
li{list-style-type:decimal;}
```

I would like solutions for the above provided the below..

- It should not be a sprite/background image solution
- I am only looking for a solution where I have to use a border-radius and background-color on the list items, which I tried, but could not work the way I want in my reference Image.

Awaiting Solutions.

Comment: Have you tried using a background image on the li?

Comment: I am not looking for a background image/sprite solution. I am only looking for a solution where I have to use a border-radius and background-color on the list items, which I tried, but could not work the way I want in my reference Image. - @furrie

Comment: `border-radius` alone makes it very difficult to solve the problem because to achieve a _circle_ with border radius, it implies that the element needs `0` width/height, I think... That would make the content (ie the decimal inside) unreadable, I believe.

Comment: From a Markup Point: Why don't you use ordered lists then (<ol>) ?

Comment: I have no problems switching to `<OL>` provided i get a solution with border-radius and background-color. If you have a solution with `<OL>`, please go ahead - @mightyuhu

Comment: I answered an almost identical question a couple of years ago. See dup link above. I think I gave a fairly good solution there.

Comment: @Spudley - I saw your post, but my requirement was specific to get solution by using only border-radius and background-color. The solution that you had provided was a generic one with different options to achive the output. I am satisfied with JonasGrumann solution, as it exactly understands the question and has provided answer within the constraints stated. Anyways, thank you for your mention. :)

Comment: @Spudley - Also in your post, the OP has made changes to the HTML, where as in my case, I can only change the `<ul>` to `<ol>` and nothing more in the markup like adding `<span>`, etc.

Comment: @NathanLee - the span in the other question is his effort to get the items lined up horizontally, so it's not relevant to your question. It's not necessary for him anyway; my answer doesn't require it. Of the option I gave in my answer, the one I favoured was basically the same solution as the answer you've accepted here, although it is true that Jonas has given you the complete code, where I previously just gave the key points and left it to him to work out the rest. In any case, I'm glad you've got the solution you wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a little trick:

```css
ol {
        counter-reset: item;
        margin-left: 0;
        padding-left: 0;
    }
li {
        display: block;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
        margin-left: 2em;
    }
li:before {
        display: inline-block;
        content: counter(item) "";
        counter-increment: item;
        background: blue;
        color: white;
        display: inline-block;
        border-radius: 50%;
        margin: 0 5px ;
        padding: 0 5px;
    
    }
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I got squares on a Webkit browser... :S

Comment: Chrome? I'm using chrome and it looks fine. Or are you on safari?
edit: tested on safari, works fine for me.

Comment: Neither... `QtWeb` to be more precise: http://qtweb.net/

Comment: Supposedly it's _Safari-ish_...

Comment: I prefixed `-webkit-` and used fixed pixel size and it worked... It's my browser's problem, probably... Good job! +1

Comment: Also, don't mean to bad-mouth, but if the _length_ of the bullet numbers becomes too big, this shapes like a _pill_... :)

Comment: You are right Joum, but what if the list gets really long? you want a huge circle with 4 numbers in it or yould you prefer a pill? honetly, I'd prefer a pill

Comment: Just one quick question - @JonasGrumann. I tired to increase the padding of the cirle to give more space to the numbers inside, but somehow, they squashed. Here is a look of the actual scenario with in your linked solution. http://jsfiddle.net/DdFKN/1/ How to prevent this at the same time enlarging the cirle with symmetry if need be?

Comment: @JonasGrumann - Can you see the issue stated above?? How to resolve it??

Comment: You need to change the padding for top, bottom, right and left. http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/DdFKN/2/ or you could set a fixed width and height, and then play around with line-height and set text-align: center.

Comment: I did, but it squashes or becomes a capsule. - @JonasGrumann

Comment: @JonasGrumann definitely a pill... Although, I have to say that although it isn't the OP's wish, I would go for the background image option... less hassle in terms of cross-browser compliance and legacy browser support, I think...

Comment: I would too, but this guy here asked a css solution. You're right though, it's not the best solution if you want the exact result in every browser

Comment: Um... this JSFiddle link is getting hijacked somehow, taking you to a Spanish iPhone 5c ad.