# How can I make number 1 in css?

Tags: colors, numbers

How can I make number 1 like this in css ??
The number in the circle [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0h47.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

See similar questions already answered in the threads linked below.

[HTML + CSS: Numbered list with numbers inside of circles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5732836/html-css-numbered-list-with-numbers-inside-of-circles)

[UL List items with styled decimal numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18636050/ul-list-items-with-styled-decimal-numbers)